# The next_posts_link() show me a aditional page in blank

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, next-post-link

**The description**

Hi, I am using a custom post type and a loop through the values ​​I show.

I'm using a term ($ term) that comes from a previous page in the loop to only show related items.

Just for a test run I configured in the administration of wordpress in the reading section, show only two post.

I'm also using a custom post type associated taxonomy as follows:

```
<?php 
  // Argumentos del loop
  $argumentos = array (
    'post_type' => 'placas',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'firmas',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $term
      )
    )
  );

  $query_productos= new WP_Query($argumentos);
?>
```

The pagination made ​​this way works well

```
<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
```

**The Problem**

But I need to display 4 post, so try this.

This shows me 4 post related to the term

```
 <?php 
  // Argumentos del loop
  $argumentos = array (
    'post_type' => 'placas',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'firmas',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $term
      )
    )
  );

  $query_productos= new WP_Query($argumentos);
 ?>
```

The problem is that the links next returns me an extra one, without content. 
Only have 6 post published and I should only have 2 pages for paging, but actually get 3 and the last third is empty.

How I can fix it so that only the necessary pages have not an extra that is empty?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are running a custom query (`$query_productos`), but your `next_posts_link` is using information from the *main query* (`$wp_query`) to determine whether or not to show a link to the next page.

See the example on [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query) for use with `WP_Query`, by passing `max_num_pages` from your custom query -

```
<?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts', $query_productos->max_num_pages ); ?>
```