# Pagination with 5 posts per page

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination

I'm trying to create a paginated list of posts, and have used the Codex to write some code but I appear to be doing something wrong.

These are my `wp_query` args

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
            $the_query = new WP_Query(
                array
                    (
                        'posts_per_page' => 5,
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'paged' => $paged
                    )
            );
```

The content of `$paged` does output as `1` which would be expected

I've added `next_posts_link` to my `if` statement but they don't show.

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                previous_posts_link( '« Newer Entries' );
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $the_query->the_post();
                    echo '<div class="news-item">';
                        // post stuff here
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                next_posts_link( 'Older Entries »', 0 );
            }
```

### EDIT

The page on which this shows is not a front page, but is a static page I created. I created `page-news.php` template and then created a page called 'News' and that it where this code resides. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The next\_posts\_link() show me a aditional page in blank](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133657/the-next-posts-link-show-me-a-aditional-page-in-blank)

Answer (score 5):

This is working for me on a single page using a template. Just be sure to set `next_posts_link( 'Older Entries »', $the_query->max_num_pages );`.

```
// set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : '1';
$args = array (
    'nopaging'               => false,
    'paged'                  => $paged,
    'posts_per_page'         => '5',
    'post_type'              => 'post',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    previous_posts_link( '« Newer Entries' );

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<div class="news-item">';
            // post stuff here
                echo '<h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text">' . the_title() . '</h1>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    next_posts_link( 'Older Entries »', $query->max_num_pages );

} else {
    // no posts found
    echo '<h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text">No Posts Found</h1>';
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link
- https://generatewp.com/wp_query/

Comment: The page on which this shows is not a front page, but is a static page I created. I created `page-news.php` template and then created a page called 'News' and that it where this code resides. Could that be the reason?

Comment: What changes have you made to my code? I can't find the change.

Comment: I was testing on the front page outside the main loop, I'll test this out on a static page and let you know if it is any different.

Comment: So, looks like it does go away when you put this inside a template. Now that I have a working example I can test further, one sec.

Comment: And this makes your answer different to mine.....???????

Comment: @user1486133, this is working great now. Just add `$the_query->max_num_pages` to your `next_posts_link` instead of 0.

Comment: @jgraup thanks, yes this was the correct solution. Thanks for presenting it and not being condescending along the way :)